# find parent of a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to be able to tell what's opening an object where a control is sitting.

I have a procedure that refreshes comboboxes but I will never know whether the combobox is sitting on a form, a subform or inside another subform (2 levels of subforms)

Now, on opening of the form, I hardcode that info to a hidden control and it's passed to a procedure, but I was wondering if there's a way to do something like this, instead of me hardcoding.

it will be either or, depending on where the combobox is sitting

```
    VMainForm = Me.Parent.Name
    VMainForm = Me.Name
    VMainForm = Me.Parent.Name '(? not even sure how to do this one,
'this would be where the combo is sitting inside another subform,
' so, there's Main!Subform1@Subform2)
```

Even better solution would be to get the full path to the subform.

So, if I'm on the 2nd subform, I'd get mainform!subform1!subform2

If I'm on a subform, I'd get mainform!subform1

If I'm on main, I'd get mainform.

Answer (score 0):

And you didn't even try?

```vb
VMainFormName = Me.Parent.Name
```

This will, of course, fail if not a subform. So either catch that error or loop the `Forms` collection for having the form of the control.

Comment: Exactly, it will fail if it's not a subform, and if it's a subforn within a subforn, then I will get the wrong answer. I was trying to see how to do this where I will get the highest parent. Or, even better, how to get the full set of subforms and the main form. So, if I'm on the 2nd subform, I'd get the parent, first sub and this sub. If I'm on a main, I'd get main. If I'm on the subform, I'd get main and sub. How do I loop through forms of only the current set? Won't the forms give me all open forms? There can be others, besides this one open.

Comment: Yes, the Forms collection holds all open forms which excludes all subforms. So, if the parent is not found in Forms, it will also be a subform.

Comment: Problem is that I have no way to know which of the open ones is my parent and not some other form. But I have an idea on how to write this.

Comment: It will be the form named equal to `Me.Parent.Name`.

Comment: or me.parent.parent.name.